# SQL - if something then do this if nothing do nothing

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, case-when

I have a column with many nulls in table 1, but now and then there is a value. If there is a value, I want to go to table 2 and take the the corresponding value from there. This should create an extra column called `user_original`:

```
CASE
   WHEN table1.user_changed IS NOT NULL 
      THEN table2.user_original 
      ELSE -- do nothing  
END as user_original
```

I basically want to replace

> is nothing

Is this correct ? How can this be done? Is there a better way?

Comment: . . Sample data and desired results would help.  How do you know which row to access in `table2`?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean you need below

```
 CASE
    WHEN table1.user_changed IS NOT NULL 
   THEN table2.user_original
    END as user_original
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a correlated subquery?

```
(CASE WHEN table1.user_changed IS NOT NULL 
      THEN (SELECT table2.user_original FROM table2 WHERE table2.? = table1.?) 
 END) as user_original
```

The `?` is for the columns that identifying "corresponding" values.

If this is the case, you can probably simplify this to:

```
(SELECT table2.user_original FROM table2 WHERE table2.? = table1.?) as user_original
```

My guess is there will be no matching value if the original value is `NULL`.